# MySQL calculating percentages, can I use a variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, count, percentage

I have a query that returns the amount of sessions, and the amount of orders made in those sessions. Simple stuff, but what I'd like to do is show the percentage of sessions that an order is made in.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table.session //Save this as variable 'Amount1'?
WHERE ses_Date BETWEEN ('2006/01/01') AND ('2011/01/01')
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table.session
WHERE Ses_ID
IN
(
SELECT Ses_ID FROM session //Save this as variable 'Amount2'?
JOIN table.order ON order.Session_ID = session.Ses_ID
WHERE ses_Date BETWEEN ('2006/01/01') AND ('2011/01/01')
GROUP by ses_ID
)

//Then do this, Display the percentage of the two
union all   
Select(SUM(amount2) /SUM(amount1) * 100)
```

In the comment on the code I have written what I would like to do in theory, I hope that helps.

Comment: those are not valid mysql date strings. they should be yyyy-mm-dd. And no, this will not work. each member query in a union is independent of the others. you cannot use a value from one query in another query in the same union.

Comment: Oh right, that bit is still working as I wanted it too, but thanks.

Comment: @Springfox have you not tried what you have up there, taking the above suggestion into consideration?

Comment: I have, but you can't have to select statements in the same query section. How would I get the value? Sorry, I'm so new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM table.session
                   WHERE ses_Date BETWEEN ('2006/01/01') AND ('2011/01/01')) * 100

FROM table.session
WHERE Ses_ID
IN
(
SELECT Ses_ID FROM session //Save this as variable 'Amount2'?
JOIN table.order ON order.Session_ID = session.Ses_ID
WHERE ses_Date BETWEEN ('2006/01/01') AND ('2011/01/01')
GROUP by ses_ID
)
```